# Shortening the length of a dataset

Tags: dataframe, powerbi, powerquery

I have a dataset like this, goes on for many thousands of rows, what im trying to achive is  a way to shorten the dataset so in the case that the dataset contains multiple rows with the same layer sort in a row im left with the top and buttom rows. In this case what would mean something like this:

[image: Example of data set, with values needed to extract marked]

| BorID | Depth1 | Depth2 | Layer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B1(192.2215) | 0.1 | 0.8 | S |
| B1(192.2215) | 0.8 | 2.4 | ML |
| B1(192.2215) | 2.4 | 3.9 | S |
| B1(192.2215) | 3.9 | 10.7 | ML |
| B1(192.2215) | 10.7 | 13.5 | S |

Is there any way to achive that getting the lowest value from each Deapth1 and the highest value from each Deapth2 if Layer is the same value?

BorID is a unique key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

(a) created an offset of all rows so I can compare to values of row beneath (b) if there is a difference in BorID or Layer then use the RowID, otherwise use null (c) fill that new column down (d) group on that column and in the grouping, create table from first row and last row of that table (e) expand and remove extra column

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//offset data one row
    MinusOne =  #table({"Column1"}, {{null}}) & Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.RemoveLastN(Source,1)),1),
    custom1 = Table.ToColumns(Source) & Table.ToColumns(MinusOne ), 
    custom2 = Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames(Source)&Table.ColumnNames(MinusOne ) ),

#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(custom2, "Custom", each if [BorID]<>[Column1] or [Layer]<>[Column5] then [Rowid] else null),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Custom"}, {{"Count", each 
         #table(
             {"BorId","Depth1","Depth2","Layer"},
             {{
                  Table.FirstN(_,1){0}[BorID],
                  Table.FirstN(_,1){0}[Depth1],
                  Table.LastN(_,1){0}[Depth2],
                  Table.FirstN(_,1){0}[Layer]
             }}
          )
, type table}}),
#"Expanded Count" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Count", {"BorId", "Depth1", "Depth2", "Layer"}, {"BorId", "Depth1", "Depth2", "Layer"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Count",{"Custom"})  
in #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

| BorID | Depth1 | Depth2 | Latert hickness | Layer | Layer sort | Rowid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0.1 | 0.15 | 5 | S | 1ML | 1 |
| a | 0.15 | 0.4 | 9 | S | 2S | 2 |
| a | 0.4 | 0.8 | 6 | S | 3S | 3 |
| a | 0.8 | 1.25 | 9 | ML | 4S | 4 |
| a | 1.25 | 1.75 | 5 | ML | 5ML | 5 |
| a | 1.75 | 2.4 | 7 | ML | 6ML | 6 |
| a | 2.4 | 2.75 | 4 | S | 7ML | 7 |
| a | 2.75 | 3.25 | 3 | S | 8ML | 8 |
| a | 3.25 | 3.9 | 7 | S | 9ML | 9 |
| a | 3.9 | 4.25 | 6 | ML | 10ML | 10 |
| a | 4.25 | 4.75 | 4 | ML | 11ML | 11 |
| a | 4.75 | 5.25 | 1 | ML | 12ML | 12 |
| a | 5.25 | 5.75 | 4 | ML | 13ML | 13 |
| a | 5.75 | 6.25 | 4 | ML | 14ML | 14 |
| a | 6.25 | 6.75 | 4 | ML | 15ML | 15 |
| a | 6.75 | 7.25 | 4 | ML | 16ML | 16 |
| a | 7.25 | 7.75 | 3 | ML | 17ML | 17 |
| a | 7.75 | 8.25 | 4 | ML | 18S | 18 |
| a | 8.25 | 8.75 | 4 | ML | 19S | 19 |
| a | 8.78 | 9.1 | 1 | ML | 20S | 20 |
| a | 9.1 | 9.75 | 8 | ML | 21S | 21 |
| a | 9.75 | 10.5 | 8 | ML | 22S | 22 |
| a | 10.5 | 10.75 | 8 | S | 23S | 23 |
| a | 10.75 | 11.5 | 8 | S | 24S | 24 |
| a | 11.5 | 11.8 | 3 | S | 25S | 25 |
| a | 11.8 | 12.25 | 8 | S | 26S | 26 |
| a | 12.25 | 12.75 | 4 | S | 27S | 27 |
| a | 12.75 | 13.25 | 3 | S | 28S | 28 |
| a | 13.25 | 13.5 | 9 | S | 29S | 29 |